# Como parar um loop Each javascript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um mecanismo de busca num rank para bot na twitch.tv segue o codigo abaixo

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const URL ='https://shadowarena.pearlabyss.com/en-US/Arena?battleType=0&server=sa'
let rankYoda;
async function acesso(){
    const response = await request(URL)
    const $ = cheerio.load(response)
    $('.box_list_area').each((i, e) => {
        const name = $(e).find('.thum_name').text()
        const rank = $(e).find('.thum_rank').text()
        if(name === "YoDaSL"){
            rankYoda = rank
        }

        }
        )}      
acesso()
console.log(rankYoda)
```

Sempre que rodo, ele me retorna no console o valor `undefined`, e eu gostaria que quando tal nome "YoDaSL" seja encontrado, parasse o loop e associasse a uma variavel fora do loop, para poder dar console.log nela, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Olá! Vc declarou a variável `let rankYoda;` antes da função assíncrona. Até aí tudo bem. Logo após a função vc executou a função e fez um console.log pra ver o valor da variável. O valor da variável é undefined pq a função onde vc quer atribuir um valor a ela é assíncrona, ou seja, não é no mesmo momento que o JS é executado. Faz um teste de olho: olhe pro seu código de cima pra baixo em uma fração se segundo. A função `acesso()` já retornou alguma coisa? Com certeza não, pq ela é assíncrona, ou seja, não respeita o tempo, depende do retorno.

Comment: Entendi, mas como eu poderia fazer isso então? Sou bem iniciante em javascript, dei umas pesquisadas mas não encontrei nada...

Comment: Use a lógica e a criatividade.

Answer (score 0):

Você está usando funções assíncronas, isso significa que o javascript roda a sua função "paralelamente" ao restante do código e você está tentando trabalhar acessar de forma síncrona.

Funções assíncronas executam com callbacks, são funções que executam quando a função principal terminar, exemplo:

```js
const URL ='https://httpbin.org/get';
$.get(URL, r => console.log(r));
console.log("Meu log");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Perceba que ao executar o snippet, mesmo a função **$.get** executando primeiro, "Meu log" é o primeiro a aparecer no console. Isso acontece porque o javascript só executa o **console.log(r)** quando a requisição estiver terminada.

Na sua função então eu sugiro as seguintes mudanças:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const URL ='https://shadowarena.pearlabyss.com/en-US/Arena?battleType=0&server=sa'
let rankYoda;
// já que está usando "await" no request e retornando o valor isso disponibilizará os dados para usarmos na outra função
async function requestData(){
    const response = await request(URL)
    const $ = cheerio.load(response);
    return $;
}
// aqui os dados carregados pelo cheerio estarão no parâmetro $
function searchUserRank(user, $){
    $('.box_list_area').each((i, e) => {
        const name = $(e).find('.thum_name').text()
        const rank = $(e).find('.thum_rank').text()
        if(name === user){
            return rank;
        }

    });
};
cheerioData = requestData();
rankYoda = searchUserRank("YoDaSL", cheerioData);
console.log(rankYoda);
```

Não testei mas acredito que seja algo próximo a isso que você está procurando

Comment: Opa mano, obrigado pela ajuda! Testei o seu codigo, e está retornando o seguinte erro: `$('.box_list_area').each((i, e) => {
    ^

TypeError: $ is not a funnctio` Mesmo assim, obrigado pelo norte!